# Active Directory exception asp .net

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

```
public bool IsUserGroupMember(string user, string unit)
{
    bool member = false;

    try
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        string[] groups = unit.Split(',');
        foreach (string word in groups)
        {
            GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, word);

            if (grp != null)
            {
                foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(true))
                {
                    if (p.SamAccountName == user)
                    {
                        member = true;
                        grp.Dispose();
                        ctx.Dispose();
                        return member;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                grp.Dispose();
                ctx.Dispose();
                return member;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (COMException)
    {
        return member;
    }

    return member;
}
```

I'm using the method above to find if a user is member of a group in Active Directory, recursively. It works well..although sometimes I get a weird exception.

Specified method is not supported.
foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(true)) is red (sorry I can't upload a picture of the exception). The weirdest thing is that it seems to be thrown randomly, and if I refresh the page it works well..

I tried to find a solution on the Internet but no happy news for now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with a solution!

I just had to add my domain name, as follow:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain");
```

It solved the problem right away!

And about the slowness..I used cookies, following this [link](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/cookies/).

Answer (score 0):

You should do this the other way around: get the user and then the authorization groups that this user is a member of - this call (`.GetAuthorizationGroups` on the `UserPrincipal`) ***already is*** searching the groups recursively for you!

```
public bool IsUserGroupMember(string user, string unit)
{
    bool isMember = false;

    try
    {
        // put the PrincipalContext in a using(..) block - then it's 
        // automatically, safely and properly disposed of at the end
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            // get the user
            UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user);

            if(up != null)
            {
                // get the authorization groups for the user
                // this call is *RECURSIVELY* enumerating all groups
                // that this user is a member of
                var authGroups = up.GetAuthorizationGroups();

                // now that you have the groups - just determine if the user
                // is a member of the group you're looking for......
            }
        }
    }
    catch (COMException comEx)
    {
        isMember = false;
    }

    return isMember;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @marc_s. I understand your code. The only issue now is that I'm getting this exeption: 'up.GetAuthorizationGroups()' threw an exception of type 'System.AppDomainUnloadedException' System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearchResult<System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal> {System.AppDomainUnloadedException}. How do I fix it? :)

Comment: Hi @marc_s, can you give me any new hint please? I'm still stuck with my method, which also takes loooong time to process; result: The initial page takes for ever to load.. :(